# How to change layer, into background in photoshop in cs6

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a problem in photoshop.. everytime i upload a picture , it would always be put into layer and not background. I am a beginner so yeah lol.. Help! 
[image]

Comment: Layer -> New -> Background from layer

Answer (score 1):

Right click the layer and select "duplicate layer" to copy and unlock it. It will show up as "Layer 1".  There's no special significance of having a layer titled "Background" vs. "Layer 0". "Background" can refer to the bottom layer of any Photoshop file.  See this post for more info on the significance of background vs. layer 0: [Photoshop Background layer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/photoshop-background-layer?rq=1)

Like that post mentions, it's a good idea to keep an unaltered copy of your photo as the background or Layer 0 file,just in case something happens during your photo manipulation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is a significance. For example when resizing a background layer, it will not create a semi-transparent bevel to the entire image - for a normal layer it does, because it uses the pixels "around" your frame to calculate the result color.

Answer (score -1):

It is because thats a default when you open an image the best way to have background it is open a new file set up all size and then put an image in this open file